# Controller not redirecting where I'm expecting it to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use a specific controller action to redirect the user to the registration page, but it's not working.

In my users_controller.rb, I have:

```
def pre_approved_with_code_action
  @code = params[:code]
  if params[:commit] = 'Cancel'
    redirect_to root_url
    return
  end
  if params[:commit] = 'Create Account'
    flash[:notice] = 'Please register as a new user'
    redirect_to new_user_registration_path(:discount_code => @code)
    return
  end
  if params[:commit] = 'Login And Retry'
    redirect_to new_user_registration_path(:notice => 'Please register as a new user', :discount_code => @code)
    return
  end
end
```

The log file says:

```
Started POST "/pre_approved_with_code_action" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-20 10:05:43 -0700

Processing by UsersController#pre_approved_with_code_action as HTML

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sWENK4ZhisSKHQswUZkDcq8ZxsXU+ym9wQqnYwgPIo4=", "code"=>"SPK_2014", "commit"=>"Create Account"}

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
```

So, it's redirecting to root_url, not new_user_registration_path. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple mistake, you need 2 equals signs

instead of `if params[:commit] = 'Cancel'` it should be `if params[:commit] == 'Cancel'`

Comment: Yes, this is the way. Disregard my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
def pre_approved_with_code_action
  @code = params[:code]
  if params[:commit] == 'Cancel'
    redirect_to root_url
    return
  end
  if params[:commit] == 'Create Account'
    flash[:notice] = 'Please register as a new user'
    redirect_to new_user_registration_path(:discount_code => @code)
    return
  end
  if params[:commit] == 'Login And Retry'
    redirect_to new_user_registration_path(:notice => 'Please register as a new user', :discount_code => @code)
    return
  end
end
```

Condition should have `==`. `=` always evaluates to true if the right hand side is a non null value

Comment: Yikes,of course. Not enough sleep and of course I copied and pasted without checking.